# Error: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`? JSX element

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the error:

> Error: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`? JSX element

With this code:

```
function CompositeCntl() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Button />
    <Display />
    <div/>
    );
}
```

Comment: Closing for "a typo" to this unique Q & A is against the spirit of [SO] in sharing solutions as people are encouraged to answer their own questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering

Answer (score 4):

{<`div`/> }--> self-closing
{<`div></div`>} ---> closing tag

Comment: This just got me!  `<div className="name">(profile.name}</div>` The brackets around the profile.name are different!

Answer (score 3):

I accidentally put the slash after the closing div:

```
 <div/>
```

This is how to correct it:

```
function CompositeCntl() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Button />
    <Display />
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this for the community, its OK https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Another cause:

```
function Button(props) {
  const handleClick = () => props.onClickFunction(props.increment)}>
     {props.increment};
    return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}
    </button>
    );
}
```

Solution, the position of the closing tag `>` :

```
function Button(props) {
  const handleClick = () => props.onClickFunction(props.increment)}
     {props.increment};
    return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
    </button>
    );
}
```